# How to do easy forecast app using Javascript?

Tags: json, api, forecast

I was trying to do easy forecast app using javascript and API from https://openweathermap.org.

(
*I was watching ytb tutorial and doesn't work for me*
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXrDEA3SIOQ&t=1s
)

**But everytime when I enter the city all that happens is the alert pops up saying “Wrong city name!”.**

**Do you have any idea how to fix it?**
Thank you

correct output is on the screen below
[image]

```js
var button= document.querySelector('.button');
var inputValue = document.querySelector('.inputValue');
var name = document.querySelector('.name');
var temp = document.querySelector('.temp');
var desc = document.querySelector('.desc');


button.addEventListener('click', function(name){
fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+inputValue.value+'&appid=497df9aa02775d8c6cdec3c6d0cd159c')
    
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  var tempValue = data['main']['temp'];
  var nameValue = data['name'];
  var descValue = data['weather'][0]['description'];

  main.innerHTML = nameValue;
  desc.innerHTML = "Desc - "+descValue;
  temp.innerHTML = "Temp - "+tempValue;
  input.value ="";

})

.catch(err => alert("Wrong city name!"));
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>OpenWeatherMap Api</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the city" class="inputValue">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
    </div>
 

  <div class="display">
    
      <h1 class="name" id="name"></h1>
      <p class="temp"></p> 
      <p class="desc"></p>
    
  </div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some major bugs in the code that I fixed and commented on.

1. variable and class named `name` was in collision in few browsers so I've rennamed it to `city`
2. Instead of `.catch` I've used `try catch` inside of the last `then` and I am logging the real `error` thrown by exception instead of `"Wrong city name!"` which is false
3. variable `main` didn't exist
4. some attributes of `data` might not be defined so I've used optional chaining `?.`

Much more conditions needs to be treated (ex. negative response from server) but I hope it helps at the start.

```js
var button= document.querySelector('.button');
var input = document.querySelector('.inputValue');
// rennamed variable `name` because it is reserved in JS
var city = document.querySelector('.city');
var temp = document.querySelector('.temp');
var desc = document.querySelector('.desc');

const baseUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
const apiKey = "497df9aa02775d8c6cdec3c6d0cd159c";
const loadData=(event)=>{
  fetch(baseUrl+input.value+'&appid='+apiKey)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        try {
          const tempValue = data?.main?.temp;
          const nameValue = data?.name;
          const descValue = data?.weather[0]?.description;
          
          // `main` was not defined. I've used `city`?
          city.innerHTML = nameValue;
          desc.innerHTML = "Desc - "+descValue;
          temp.innerHTML = "Temp - "+tempValue;
          input.value ="";
        } catch (err) {
           // hard coded error "Wrong city name!" was giving you falsy information
           // log the real error
           console.log(err);
        }
     });
}

button.addEventListener('click',loadData)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>OpenWeatherMap Api</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Zadejte město" class="inputValue">
    <input type="submit" value="Odeslat" class="button">
  </div>
  <div class="display">
      <h1 class="city"></h1>
      <p class="temp"></p> 
      <p class="desc"></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```